# Could pgpool be locking tables

Tags: postgresql

I had an issue today where I could not insert into a single table(I think the table was locked).

This was resolved once I revered my application back to hitting the master server for all of my connections.

Is it possible for pgpool to be locking a table and not releasing it until the connection is closed?

Thanks!

Comment: did you verify that pgpool knew which one was master and which was standby? Two weeks ago, I found that a developer was issuing `pg_terminate_backend` through pgpool (which is all bad). pg_pool sent everything to standby and no inserts/updates worked.

Comment: yes, I am using pgpoolAdmin to monitor the pooling and the correct servers are set to primary and standby.  I was also able to insert into other tables just not this one.